# Alter mysql table default value and NULLvalue?

Tags: mysql

How can i make a table field with default value "none" and null value "no"?

When i create a table with following code it always add default value NULL and null to yes

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `test` INT(11) AFTER `test1`
```

Comment: An integer column cannot have 'none' as default value, since 'none' is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `test` INT NOT NULL AFTER `test1`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ALTER column SET DEFAULT 'none'.
```

For replacing NULL with NO you don't have to alter the table just do it in your query :

```
SELECT COALESCE(columnWhichisNull,'no'))
FROM myTable ;
```

`COALESCE` checks if a value from a column is null and replaces it with your desired character